# Rolling mean for panel with 3 identifiers in Stata

Tags: stata, mean

I have an unbalanced panel with 3 identifiers (date, company and person) for which I want to calculate rolling means for my variable (`price`) over the previous 90 days for each company and date. As I assign the panel with `tsset` I get an error message `repeated time values within panel`. Since each person in my panel belongs to several companies, I have several company-person pairs for each date. 
Here is my code so far:

```
tsset company_id date_id
tsegen Mean_90days = rowmean(L(0/90).price)
```

Is there any way how to make such calculation?

My solution was to generate a `company_person_id` using `group(company_id person_id)`, to calculate mean for each `company_person_id date` observation and to use mean `egen=mean()` to aggregate `by (company_id date_id)`. However I am still not sure if it's plausible.

Comment: Your two-step solution seems sound, because of the way means work, but there is a more direct route: see my answer.

Comment: Actually, the work-around would be problematic unless you took account of the fact that different means over (company, person) pairs could be based on different numbers of measurements. The correct work-around would be a weighted mean.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Nick Cox  - a weighted mean is better in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have it both ways with that machinery. If you declare that companies are panels, that won't wash because of replicates for the same panel and time. `tsset` will fail and `tsegen` (SSC, as you should explain) won't budge. If the `tsset` framework refuses, then whatever is based on it won't and can't help.

If you declare that (company, person) pairs are panels, your calculation can go ahead, but you will not pool values for different persons in the same company. which seems to be what you want.

But there is good news.

`rangestat` (SSC) (announced [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1333361-new-on-ssc-rangestat-a-program-to-generate-statistics-using-observations-within-range)) should help.

Your command would I think resemble

```
rangestat (mean) price, interval(date_id -90 0) by(company)
```

Note that this is calculating for the previous 90 days **and** the present, as in your call.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think `rangestat` is what I need here.